# Area Under an A/C signal wave form

Tags: power, ac

I am working on a circuit that uses power from the wall outlet (50hz and 60hz) and I would to calculate the amount of power at different time between 
(0 and pi).  The circuit has a power Factor of 1.

1. So, for example, if I wanted to know at what point between (0 and pi) the power would be say 10% of the total power, how would I calculate it?
2. Or, how would I know the level of the power at say pi/4 or pi/6?

Thanks very much for your time guys.

Comment: Integration. Solve the bound integral for 0.1

Comment: Or if you don't like integration... Simpson's or Trapezoid Rule :)

Comment: Again mixup between power and energy

Answer (score 1):

"*... 10% of the total power ...*" You probably mean maximum power at peak of sine.

\$ P = I^2R \$ so at 10% power *I* will be \$ \sqrt {0.1}I_{pk} = 0.316 I_{pk} \$.

The current will reach 0.316 of peak at \$ sin^{-1}(0.316) = 18.4° \text { or } 180-18.4 = 161.6°\$.

You should be able to work out your question 2 by reversing the above sequence.

Comment: Thanks for the improvement, @Harry.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a sinusoidal voltage expressed in PerUnit and consider a resistive load. With a resistive load drawing 0.5PU (when compared to the peak of the voltage).

[image]

The peak power is obviously \$\hat V \cdot \hat I\$ but the frequency is doubled

\$1\cdot Sin(2\cdot\pi \cdot 50 \cdot t) \cdot \frac{1}{2}\cdot Sin(2\cdot\pi \cdot 50\cdot t) = \frac{1}{2}Sin^2(2\cdot\pi \cdot 50)\$ and via double angle theory:

\$ \frac{1}{2}Sin^2(2\cdot\pi \cdot 50 \cdot t) = \frac{1}{4} - \frac{1}{4} Cos( 2\cdot 2\cdot\pi \cdot 50 \cdot t)\$

you stated you are interested in when this is 10% of the peak. The peak power is 0.5PU, thus the equation to solve is:

\$ \frac{1}{4} - \frac{1}{4} Cos( 2\cdot 2\cdot\pi \cdot 50 \cdot t) = 0.05 \$ (10% of 0.5)

rearranging to isolate time:

\$ \frac{1}{4} - \frac{1}{4} Cos( 2\cdot 2\cdot\pi \cdot 50 \cdot t) = 0.05 \$

\$ 1 -  Cos( 2\cdot 2\cdot\pi \cdot 50 \cdot t) = 0.2 \$

\$ Cos( 2\cdot 2\cdot\pi \cdot 50 \cdot t) = 0.8 \$

\$  2\cdot 2\cdot\pi \cdot 50 \cdot t = cos^{-1}0.8 \$

\$ t= \frac{ cos^{-1} (0.8) }{ 2\cdot 2\cdot\pi \cdot 50} = 1.024ms\$

or left as an angle

\$ \theta = \frac{ cos^{-1} (0.8) }{ 2 } = 0.321 radians = 18.43^{\circ}\$

[image]

Comment: thank you very much for addressing my question.

Comment: 1/  You stated " Consider a sinusoidal voltage expressed in PerUnit and consider a resistive load. With a resistive load drawing 0.5PU (when compared to the peak of the voltage)."  How do you arrive at the PerUnit value of 0.5PU?    2/  Also, Is the value "50" in the equation " 1/4−1/4  Cos(2⋅2⋅π⋅50⋅t) = 0.05 (10% of 0.5)" the frequency of the voltage?

Comment: The reason I took this route was to stress the fact power follows a sin^2 profile and thus a simple trig isn't good enough. I got 0.5PU by stating 1PU voltage and 0.5PU current -> 0.5PU power. Yes 50 in this is the frequency

Answer (score 0):

Well, a general \$\sin\$ wave is given by:

$$\text{V}(t)=\hat{\text{a}}_1\cdot\sin\left(\omega t+\varphi_1\right)\tag1$$

Using linear components we get a current that is also a \$\sin\$ wave but with a different amplitude and phase with the same frequency, so:

$$\text{I}(t)=\hat{\text{a}}_2\cdot\sin\left(\omega t+\varphi_2\right)\tag2$$

The power that is generated is given by:

$$\text{P}(t)=\text{V}(t)\cdot\text{I}(t)=\hat{\text{a}}_1\cdot\sin\left(\omega t+\varphi_1\right)\cdot\hat{\text{a}}_2\cdot\sin\left(\omega t+\varphi_2\right)\tag3$$

The total power, over the interval \$[0,\pi]\$, is given by:

$$\text{P}(\pi)-\text{P}(0)=\hat{\text{a}}_1\cdot\sin\left(\omega t+\varphi_1\right)\cdot\hat{\text{a}}_2\cdot\sin\left(\omega t+\varphi_2\right)-\hat{\text{a}}_1\cdot\sin\left(\omega t+\varphi_1\right)\cdot\hat{\text{a}}_2\cdot\sin\left(\omega t+\varphi_2\right)=$$
$$\hat{\text{a}}_1\cdot\sin\left(\omega\pi+\varphi_1\right)\cdot\hat{\text{a}}_2\cdot\sin\left(\omega\pi+\varphi_2\right)-\hat{\text{a}}_1\cdot\sin\left(\varphi_1\right)\cdot\hat{\text{a}}_2\cdot\sin\left(\varphi_2\right)\tag4$$

Answer (score 0):

Good answers above.  Just wanted to point at that discretizing the problem makes it really easy too.  In the picture below i just plotted a voltage with about 25 points per 60Hz cycle.  The current is just the voltage divided by 5 ohm resistive load.  Then it is as simple as multiplying v by each i at each sample to get the power.  I plotted power on the right axis to improve clarity.

[image]

Comment: Here is formula you can use in Excel to do this, in this equation i'm using 16 samples/cycle: `=67*1.414*SIN(2*PI()*A1/16+2*PI()/3)` and i've added a 120 degree phase shift.  Column A just has sample number (e.g. A1 = 1, A2 = 2, etc.).